# Concat string with a specific operator

Tags: eclipse, emacs, notepad++

I am using Emacs, Notepad++ or Eclipse. Is there a way to cut a String in small pieces and concat them using a separator?

For instance:
Input:

```
"I like sushi and maki"
```

Output:

```
"I like" +
"sushi and" + 
"maki"
```

Comment: This is an incredibly vague question.

Comment: To whit: what length is each resultant line?  How robust does it have to be? (strings within strings?)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse (at least in the Java context) you only need to place the cursor inside the string and hit enter.  This works also in Netbeans.

Comment: I know but my string is huge (it is for testing purpose)

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you can use RegEx:  `([\w]+)\s*([\w]*)`  and then replace with `"$1 $2" +`  but then you will have to go back and remove the extraneous `+` signs from the end replacements that just have one group match.

Comment: The solution for Emacs would be the same (using replace-regexp, or query-replace-regexp bound to C-M-%). To insert a newline in the replacement string, you need to use C-q C-j.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my take at the problem. Not sure if I'm solving the right problem though :)

```
(defun split-string-words (min max)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((counted 0) (before-indent min)
        (wordcount (read-number "How many words in a line? " 7))
        (delimiter
         (read-string "Delimit with (default: \" + \") "
                      nil nil "\" + \"")))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char min)
      (while (< min max)
        (incf counted)
        (when (= counted wordcount)
          (insert delimiter)
          (backward-char)
          (incf max (length delimiter))
          (setq before-indent (point)
                counted 0)
          (newline-and-indent)
          (incf max (- (point) before-indent)))
        (forward-word)
        (setq min (point))))))
```

The use should be straight forward. Also check your editing mode for a `<mode>-insert-and-indent` function, you would like to use it instead of `newline-and-indent`.